# Cascading Combo Box to Limit Options with Multiple Joins - SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

[image: Current Database Layout]

See picture above.

I am really struggling with how to make this work.  I have a database attempting to handle questions and responses.  Each survey has questions.  Every question has an answer group that is appropriate for that question, whether it be Yes/No, or True/False, or whatever.  I am attempting to collect responses to these questions.  Where I am hitting the wall is trying to limit the answers in the tblSurveyQuestionResponse to only those answers that are in the Answer Group for that particular question.  I just cannot seems to grasp how to do this, whether I have the wrong joins or just am not writing the SQL where clause correctly.  So, for example, if a question's possible answers were only "Yes" or "No", as opposed to pulling up the entire list of answers, the combo box would only show "Yes" and "No".  I then plan to use VBA to have the answer combo box requery whenever the question changes so that only the possible answers are displayed.  Can anyone help me figure out how to do this?  Or is my DB design flawed?  Please help.  If more information is required, please let me know.  Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what the actual question is. Have you tried any code yet? You can use the `Current` event to change the `RowSource` of your answers combobox.

Comment: So, my question is, what SQL will result in limiting the options in the combo box to only those answers that belong to the Answer Group.

I started with the following:

SELECT tblAnswerGroupAnswer.AnswerGroupAnswerID, tblAnswerGroupAnswer.AnswerID
FROM tblAnswerGroupAnswer
ORDER BY tblAnswerGroupAnswer.Order;

I know there should be a WHERE clause.  What I think I am looking for is WHERE tblSurveyQuestionResponse.SurveyQuestionID = tblSurveyQuestion.SurveyQuestionID and where tblAnswerGroupAnswer.AnswerGroupID = tblSurveyQuestion.AnswerGroupID

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, edit your question and add it there (and format as code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this!

Create a new query, start with `tblQuestion`. Then follow your JOINs, adding all tables until you have reached `tblAnswer`.

Add a criteria: `tblQuestion.QuestionID = Forms![YourQuestionForm]!QuestionID`

And add the field(s) from `tblAnswer` that you want to have in your combobox.

Save the query, and use it as RowSource for the combobox.

And in `Form_Current`, do `Me.cboAnswer.Requery`, so it will always use the current QuestionID in the combobox query.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That is a much simpler solution than what I was thinking.  I was ending up with some massive WHERE clauses.  This approach seems to be working!  Thank you again.